# Casting an item to either of two options

Tags: ios, swift, casting, codable

I am wondering about a way which casts an item to either of `Type1` or `Type2`.

To be more clear, let me give an example

Let's say we have two different `struct` inherits from `Decodable`

```
struct Decodable1: Decodable { ... }

struct Decodable2: Decodable { ... }
```

I use those `Decodable`s to parse json which is acquired from `http` requests. On several places I have to use these data as;

```
let data1 : [Decodable1] = [...]
let data2 : [Decodable2] = [...]
var data : [Decodable] = []

switch mode {
case .one:
   data = data1 as! [Decodable1]
case .two:
   data = data2 as! [Decodable2]
}
```

I know that this way is pretty straight forward and I think It would not be harmful if I implement this at just one place. However, the application is really depend that mode variable (which I provide as `ReSwift State`) and as a result I am trying to find a simpler way to this. Like;

```
let data = (mode == .one) ? data1 : data2
```

Of course this does not work and throw `type mismatch error`

Can someone suggest a good way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Also my intention besides reducing the `switch` statements is reaching the defined variables inside of those `Decodable`s easily. Which means without doing any `switch` or `if-else` statement.

Is that possible?

**EDIT_2:**

I am revising my question with respect to recent comments.

Let's say I have a `class`;

```
class MyClass {
   var data1: [Decodable1] = [...]
   var data2: [Decodable2] = [...]
   var mode: Mode = .One
   func myFunc() -> [Decodable] {
      //return either data1 or data2 with respect to the mode and already casted to its type.
   }
}
```

Is a `function` like that is possible?

Comment: Note that your example contains unintended redeclarations of `data` - the first should be a `var`, and the switches assignments, not redeclaration...

Comment: oh, sorry. thanks :)

Comment: What difference does it make to cast it? the only thing you can get is a runtime exception. Why do you want to do this? If you want to use the objects, you always must cast the objects.

Comment: The simple answer is no, you cannot magically unify two different types in one variable. Swift has strict compile time typing.   If this thing is a type 1, decode it as type 1 and work with it as type 1. If it is type 2, decode it as type 2 and work with it as type 2.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please check second edit. @matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is repeated use of the `switch` - why not just create a function in the `enum` that does it? - e.g.

```
// *** OP's code ***
struct Decodable1: Decodable { /*...*/ }
struct Decodable2: Decodable { /*...*/ }
enum Mode { case one, two }

let data1: [Decodable1] = [Decodable1(), Decodable1()]
let data2: [Decodable2] = [Decodable2(), Decodable2()]
var data: [Decodable] = []

var mode: Mode = .one
switch mode {
case .one:
    data = data1 //as! [Decodable1] // cast is unnecessary
case .two:
    data = data2 //as! [Decodable2] // cast is unnecessary
}
print(data) // [__lldb_expr_18.Decodable1(), __lldb_expr_18.Decodable1()]

// *** Suggestion - extend the mode enum to make the choice... ***
extension Mode {
    func which(_ d1: [Decodable1], _ d2: [Decodable2]) -> [Decodable] {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            return data1
        case .two:
            return data2
        }
    }
}
// *** Usage ***
print(mode.which(data1, data2)) // [__lldb_expr_18.Decodable1(), __lldb_expr_18.Decodable1()]
```

Depending on your use case (which is unclear to me), you may wish to consider the ["Either" pattern](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ft13/index.html):

```
enum Either<L, R> {
    case one(L), two(R)
    init(_ left: L) { self = .one(left) }
    init(_ right: R) { self = .two(right) }
}

extension Either {
    internal init?(any: Any) {
        if let left = any as? L {
            self = .one(left)
        } else if let right = any as? R {
            self = .two(right)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    static func fromAny(_ any: [Any]) -> [Either] {
        return any.compactMap({ Either(any: $0) })
    }
}

let e = Either<Decodable1, Decodable2>.fromAny(data1)
```

Comment: yeah this would help me to get rid of `switch`es. But `Decodable1` and `Decodable2` may have different variable names. Do I have to make the casting to reach those variables? e.g. `mode.which(data1, data2).id` directly. (Assume `id` is just in `Decodable1`.)

Comment: See my updated answer about using "Either" pattern. Would help with some real use case code... :)

Comment: I have a question though, what would be the type of variable `e`?

Comment: Tried and got `Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<App.Decodable1>' (0x111c07a68) to 'Swift.Decodable' (0x111c07ce8)`

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope it is more clear right now @Grimxn